# Problem with displaying table format in matlab

Tags: matlab

[image]
I tired for displaying Value of `f(x,y)` and conclusion like above mentioned but it seem not working. here is my **code**:

```
%% displaying table
clc
clear all
syms x y
f(x,y)=x^3-3*x*y+y^3;
fx=diff(f,x);
fy=diff(f,y);
fxx=diff(fx,x);
fyy=diff(fy,y);
fxy=diff(fx,y);
D=(fxx*fyy)-(fxy)^2;
eqns=[fx==0,fy==0];
vars=[x y];
[sol_x sol_y]=solve(fx==0,fy==0,'Real',true);
conclusion={};
f_val=[];
for i=1:length(sol_x)
    if( subs(D,{x,y},{sol_x(i),sol_y(i)})>0 && subs(fxx,{x,y},{sol_x(i),sol_y(i)})>0 )
        conclusion{end+1}='min';
        f_val(end+1)=f(sol_x(i),sol_y(i));
    elseif(subs(D,{x,y},{sol_x(i),sol_y(i)})>0 && subs(fxx,{x,y},{sol_x(i),sol_y(i)})<0)
        conclusion{end+1}='max';
        f_val(end+1)=f(sol_x(i),sol_y(i));
    elseif(subs(D,{x,y},{sol_x(i),sol_y(i)})<0)
        conclusion{end+1}='saddle';
        f_val(end+1)=f(sol_x(i),sol_y(i));
    else
        conclusion{end+1}='undetermine';
        f_val(end+1)=f(sol_x(i),sol_y(i));
    end
end
conclusion'
f_val'
result=[num2cell(f_val') conclusion']
f = figure;
uit = uitable(f,'ColumnName',{'function value'; 'conclusion'},'Data',result);
```

which give me **output**:

[image: image2]

I am confused how to display Critical points like `(1,2)` in `Critical points` column. I mean how to code in order to display a **table** like in the picture. And is there any better way to code this?

Comment: Hint:  [critical points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) are just where the first derivative (in this multivariable case, the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient)) is equal to zero.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan I knew that. My problem is how to display Critical points like `(1,2)` in `Critical points` column. I mean how to code in order to display a table like in the picture.

Comment: You already managed to do it for two columns? What are your problems doing the same with the other columns ?

Comment: Because it seems unprofessional what I do(I personally thinking) Because I repeat similar code a lot. I was wondering is there any dry or professional approach to do this work @Daniel And one think I didn’t get is 'how to show coordinate like `(1,2)` in my uitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Spri4L suggested how to display points. To avoid `subs` you can make it anonymous function.

```
clc
clear all
syms x y
f=@(x,y)x.^3-3.*x.*y+y.^3;
fxx(x,y)=diff(diff(f,x),x);
fyy(x,y)=diff(diff(f,y),y);
fxy(x,y)=diff(diff(f,x),y);
D(x,y)=fxx*fyy-(fxy).^2;
conclusion={};
f_val=[];
D_val=[];
fxx_val=[];
points={};
[solx,soly]=solve(diff(f,x)==0,diff(f,y)==0,'Real',true);
for i=1:length(solx)
    if(D(solx(i),soly(i))>0 && fxx(solx(i),soly(i))>0)
        conclusion{end+1}='   min';
    elseif(D(solx(i),soly(i))>0 && fxx(solx(i),soly(i))<0)
        conclusion{end+1}='   max';
    elseif(D(solx(i),soly(i))<0)
        conclusion{end+1}='   saddle';
    else
        conclusion{end+1}='   undetermine';
    end
    points{end+1} = ['(',num2str(double(solx(i))), ',', num2str(double(soly(i))), ')'];
    f_val(end+1)=f(solx(i),soly(i));
    fxx_val(end+1)=fxx(solx(i),soly(i));
    D_val(end+1)=D(solx(i),soly(i));
end
result=[points' num2cell(f_val') num2cell(fxx_val') num2cell(D_val') conclusion'];
f=figure;
uit=uitable(f,'ColumnName',{'points';'value of f'; 'fxx'; 'D'; 'conclusion';},'Data',result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got exactly what you're looking for, but it seems you just need to change the definition of the uitable to something like:

```
uit = uitable(f,'ColumnName',{'Critical Points'; 'Value of x'; 'f_xx', },'Data',result);
```

and add in the for loop something like:

```
points{end+1} = ['(',num2str(double(sol_x(i))), ',', num2str(double(sol_y(i))), ')'];
```

and just add this into the final result cell array, as you already did with conclusion and the function value.